# Extracting a nested list with Django and replacing values

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I am building an app using the Django Rest Framework and Vue.js. I am consuming the Spotify API as well as providing data from the DRF. When i do an artist search using the following code:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    artist = services.spot_artist_search(self.kwargs['artist'])
    return Response(artist)
```

It returns exactly what I expect which is an artist search from Spotify's API. The result looks something like this.(I am only showing the first two entries for brevity)

```
{
"artists": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=adele&type=artist&offset=0&limit=10",
    "items": [
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY"
            },
            "followers": {
                "href": null,
                "total": 6175115
            },
            "genres": [
                "dance pop",
                "pop"
            ],
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY",
            "id": "4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY",
            "images": [
                {
                    "height": 1000,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ccbe7b4fef679f821988c78dbd4734471834e3d9",
                    "width": 1000
                },
                {
                    "height": 640,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/f8737f6fda048b45efe91f81c2bda2b601ae689c",
                    "width": 640
                },
                {
                    "height": 200,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/df070ad127f62d682596e515ac69d5bef56e0897",
                    "width": 200
                },
                {
                    "height": 64,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/cbbdfb209cc38b2999b1882f42ee642555316313",
                    "width": 64
                }
            ],
            "name": "Adele",
            "popularity": 85,
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY"
        },
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC"
            },
            "followers": {
                "href": null,
                "total": 3504
            },
            "genres": [],
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC",
            "id": "19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC",
            "images": [],
            "name": "Robyn Adele Anderson",
            "popularity": 42,
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC"
        },
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY"
            },
            "followers": {
                "href": null,
                "total": 477
            },
            "genres": [
                "violin"
            ],
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY",
            "id": "5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY",
            "images": [
                {
                    "height": 636,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/581e634f260b77c93c61266bc6f8f755c2417a67",
                    "width": 640
                },
                {
                    "height": 298,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/01aa0f1316ac6cc2f03306aaf851f32b20f50175",
                    "width": 300
                },
                {
                    "height": 64,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/2051799990aa97da74524fdf9757e499cc51569b",
                    "width": 64
                }
            ],
            "name": "Adele Anthony",
            "popularity": 34,
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY"
        },
```

What I would like to do is iterate through this response, and extract the first entry in the 'images' nested list, then replace the nested list with just that single first entry. The final JSON would look like this:

```
{
"artists": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=adele&type=artist&offset=0&limit=10",
    "items": [
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY"
            },
            "followers": {
                "href": null,
                "total": 6175115
            },
            "genres": [
                "dance pop",
                "pop"
            ],
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY",
            "id": "4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY",
            "images": [
                {
                    "height": 1000,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ccbe7b4fef679f821988c78dbd4734471834e3d9",
                    "width": 1000
                },

            ],
            "name": "Adele",
            "popularity": 85,
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY"
        },
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC"
            },
            "followers": {
                "href": null,
                "total": 3504
            },
            "genres": [],
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC",
            "id": "19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC",
            "images": [],
            "name": "Robyn Adele Anderson",
            "popularity": 42,
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:19RHMn8FFkEFmhPwyDW2ZC"
        },
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY"
            },
            "followers": {
                "href": null,
                "total": 477
            },
            "genres": [
                "violin"
            ],
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY",
            "id": "5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY",
            "images": [
                {
                    "height": 636,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/581e634f260b77c93c61266bc6f8f755c2417a67",
                    "width": 640
                },
            ],
            "name": "Adele Anthony",
            "popularity": 34,
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:5yUp79jSBSGdkbufl2hmcY"
        },
```

Please can you advise how i might do this? I also need to check if there is an image in the nested list as not all results will return one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try using the following

```
# result = <api call>
for i in result["artists"]["items"]:
    if "images" in i and i["images"]:
        i["images"] = [i["images"][0]]

print result
```

See if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i just tried that and i am getting a 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key' error.